# "Subquery", "sub query" or "sub-query"

Tags: compound-nouns

Should I write "subquery", "sub query" or "sub-query"?

Or is it dependent on context?

Maybe I should mention that I (try to) use American English.

(Background: I am writing an application that has queries, and in some cases subordinate queries. I need to denote these correctly in my source code, using "CamelCase". For "subquery" I would denote them "Subquery", but in the hyphen/space cases I would use "SubQuery". Which is it?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "naming, including naming programming variables/classes" is [off topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please choose a name that gives clarity to your code, above any consideration of good English.

Comment: @WeatherVane Noted. But the programming aspect is only for background. I really do want to know the right way to write this. I can remove the background part if it hurts your eyes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I suppose it does. Thank you!

Comment: In *programming* contexts, you'd normally have to use an underscore rather than a hyphen (constraints on variable names). But apparently there's no such restriction on *filenames / file-names / file_names* in Linux, and it seems to me whenever I need to type some filename like *Cookies-journal* or *bash_history*, I actually make the wrong choice more than half the time! :)